# MySql counting results with left joins doubles the results

Tags: mysql

I have this query generated by `Django` where a user has `orders` and `jobs` as related tables. `jobs` are of two types: `clean` and `wash`. I want to count for each user shown the number of orders, clean jobs and wash jobs.

One of the users has 3 clean jobs in the database but this query returns the value of 6 for column `clean_ct`. If I remove the join to the `order` table and the orders count the counts are as expected so the second `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is causing this doubling to occur. I'm suspecting a wrong `GROUP BY` but I haven't found a solution. Any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `auth_user`.`id`, 
                `auth_user`.`username`, 
                Count(DISTINCT `order`.`id`) AS `orders_ct`, 
                Count(CASE 
                        WHEN `job`.`service` = 'clean' THEN 1 
                        ELSE NULL 
                      end)                   AS `clean_ct`, 
                Count(CASE 
                        WHEN `job`.`service` = 'wash' THEN 1 
                        ELSE NULL 
                      end)                   AS `wash_ct` 
FROM   `auth_user` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `order` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `order`.`user_id` ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `job` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `job`.`user_id` ) 
GROUP  BY `auth_user`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `auth_user`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT  100
```

`clean_ct` should be 3 but returns 6

Comment: Pro debugging tip: Remove the `GROUP BY` clause to look at the data that will be aggregated. Makes it easy to spot the mistake. Do you know why you need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s instead of a plain `JOIN`? Does it logically make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two joins from the base table (`auth_user`) and both joins are to tables with 1-to-many relationship with the base table. That creates the multiple rows. If for example, an auth_user has 3 orders and 7 jobs, the join (before any group by) will result in 21 rows.

When you then `GROUP BY`, the (created) rows are counted and you get incorrect results (in the example, you'd get the job counts multiplied by 3 and the orders count multiplied by 7). Your code would manage to avoid the x7 because it uses `DISTINCT` when counting orders but not avoid the x3 when counting jobs.

One solution would be to use `DISTINCT` in all counts. In your case, you could write the "wash" count as:

```
            Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                             WHEN `job`.`service` = 'wash' THEN job.id 
                             ELSE NULL 
                           END)                   AS `wash_ct`
```

But this solution will become quite complicated and inefficient with many joins.

Another solution is to `group by` in each individual table and then join (the derived tables) to `auth_user`. Also:

- `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` in the same `SELECT` are rarely needed:
- `ELSE NULL` is the default in `CASE` expressions. (it's not a problem if you like it there, just not needed.)
- You don't need to quote all table and column names. Only reserved words - which should be avoided anyway - and names with special characters.
- It would best to avoid reserved words - like `order` - when naming tables and columns.

The query could be written:

```
SELECT au.id, 
       au.username, 
       COALESCE(orders_ct, 0) AS orders_ct, 
       COALESCE(clean_ct, 0)  AS clean_ct, 
       COALESCE(wash_ct, 0)   AS wash_ct 
FROM   auth_user AS au 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
           ( SELECT user_id,
                    Count(*)  AS orders_ct                    
             FROM   `order`
             GROUP  BY user_id
           ) AS o 
                    ON au.id = o.user_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN  
           ( SELECT user_id,
                    Count(CASE WHEN service = 'clean' THEN 1 
                          END)  AS clean_ct,
                    Count(CASE WHEN service = 'wash' THEN 1 
                          END)  AS wash_ct                            
             FROM   job
             GROUP  BY user_id
           ) AS j
                    ON au.id = j.user_id 
ORDER  BY au.id DESC 
LIMIT  100 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This construction:

```
FROM   `auth_user` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `order` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `order`.`user_id` ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `job` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `job`.`user_id` )
```

return as many rows as many rows child table has with same id
and not removed by GROUP BY

You need run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   `auth_user` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `order` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `order`.`user_id` ) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `job` 
                    ON ( `auth_user`.`id` = `job`.`user_id` ) 
ORDER  BY `auth_user`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT  100
```

for better understanding result, than add additional parameters to the query for exclude duplicates